# Test upload file with laravel 8, assertExists not working

Tags: laravel, automated-tests, phpunit

I'm testing upload the files with laravel 8.

My Controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request->file('file')->store('uploads');
        return $path;
    }
```

My test code

```
 /** @test */
    public function check_file_can_be_uploaded()
    {
        Storage::fake('uploads');
        $file = UploadedFile::fake()->image('document.pdf', 300);
        $data = Contact::factory()->make([
            'file' => $file
        ])->toArray();

        $response = $this->post(route('contact.store'), $data);

        Storage::disk('uploads')->assertExists($file->hashName());

    }
```

I see the file in storage folder, but phpunit return **Unable to find a file at path [08cnFo56Ce8RIBCwUh7eY8hTZxvdv6atMBdozSaH.pdf].
Failed asserting that false is true.**

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I know it doesn't add any value, but I’m stuck with the same error and I have no idea on how to solve this.

Comment: I didn't solve ...

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but you can call `fake()->create()` instead of `fake->image()` if you're actually testing for a file other than image, going by the .pdf in the filename, [as per the L8 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#fake-file-customization)

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same issue, as a work around I've used the following:

```
self::assertFileExists(storage_path('app/public/1/' . $file->hashName()));
```

Your experience may diff as to the path where it stores the file